# How to convert the current class name of asp.net usercontrols to string on c#?

Tags: c#, reflection, c#-4.0, classname, gettype

So I have tried GetType() but for some reason, It does include the namespace...

Does C# not have a property for a class specifying its name?

For example:

```
public class Parent : System.Web.UI.UserControl {
    public someFunction(){
        Child child = new Child();
        Console.WriteLine(child.ThePropertyThatContainsTheName);
    }
}

public class Child : Parent {
}
```

I have tried to create the Child with a string property that has the name hard-coded, but only if we could find a better workaround to this... maybe reflection or expressions...

Thanks in advance =)

Edit: I am working on user controls by the way...

Comment: Did you just call GetType().ToString() or GetType().Name?

Comment: I'm slightly confused - are you saying that GetType().Name isn't returning what you want?

Comment: I have used GetType().Name and GetType().FullName, but the problem is that they both returned the namespace, for example : `hello_web_ui_child_aspx`

Comment: by the way guys, I used this for usercontrols... =)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you are using an ASP.NET Web Application project, you will normally be using the code-behind model.

ASP.NET will dynamically generate and compile a class from your aspx/ascx file, which uses the class you defined in your code-behind file as a base class.

`this.GetType().Name` and `this.GetType().FullName` will return the name of the auto-generated class generated by ASP.NET.  This auto-generated class will subclass the UserControl/WebPage class you have defined in your code-behind file (`Inherits` keyword in the `<%@Control ...>` tag of your ascx file / `<%@Page ...>` tag of your aspx file).

If you want the name of your code-behind class, use:

`this.GetType().BaseType.Name` or `this.GetType().BaseType.FullName`

Comment: I'll try this later back home.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Type.Name` like this:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(Test).Name);
    }
}
```

or like this (if you are getting the type via `Object.GetType`):

```
using System;

class Foo { }

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Console.WriteLine(foo.GetType().Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: well, the problem really with GetType() as I have mentioned, is that it includes the namespace and changes the everything to lowercase.

Comment: Just curious, are you working with ASP.NET website and a custom control?  `Type.Name` doesn't change the case of type's name but ASP.NET does type name mangling for custom pages and user controls that may be causing what you are seeing.

Comment: Unfortunately then the type name you are seeing the actual type name. ASP.NET mangles the names of custom controls and pages to the format you are seeing - that really is the name of your type :)

Comment: Why is it designed that way? Are there no other way where we could get the exact class name as declared? =)

Answer (score 1):

Use `GetType()` and `Name`

```
Console.Writeline(child.GetType().Name);
```

or

```
Console.Writeline(child.GetType().FullName);
```

Comment: neither could be used since I have already mentioned in my question that using GetType() includes the namespace.

Comment: The Type.Name property will not contain the namespace.  Type.FullName will contain the class name.

Comment: My bad, really... I have not mentioned earlier that I was using ASP.Net UserControls

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use reflection to get base type of your variable

```
control.GetType().BaseType.Name
```

If you need I can provide deep description why it is so.

If you want you can try this code

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(((UserControl)control).AppRelativeVirtualPath)
```

This will give you the name you want, but this is not the type of the UserControl but it's file name.